# UIToolBar creating problem while application returns from background

Tags: iphone, ios4, multitasking, uitoolbar

I am using a uitoolbar in a view that is initialized using initWithFrame: method in sdk. I mean I am adding tool bar porgrammatically. While multitasking, this toolbar is creating problem. Can anyone give me some solution or a ray of light to proceed. I cant add it in xib since I am using  a custom uitablecontroller class. My code is as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];    
actionToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 373, 320, 44)];  
[actionToolbar insertSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-bar.png"]] autorelease] atIndex:0];

actionButton = [NotesList createSquareBarButtonItemWithTitle:@"Delete" target:self action:@selector(noAction:)];
flexibleSpace1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
flexibleSpace2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];    

composeButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(addNewGroup:)]autorelease];
composeButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;    
[actionToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace1, flexibleSpace2, composeButton, nil]]; 
[self.view.superview addSubview:actionToolbar];

self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);  
[self.tableView setAllowsSelectionDuringEditing:YES];   
[flexibleSpace1 retain];
[flexibleSpace2 retain];
[actionButton retain];
[composeButton retain]; 
[self parseDataForThisFile];
}
```

Comment: want to clarify the problem your are having? i cant help unless you let me know what is happening

Comment: what is your problem exactly ??

Comment: My problem is while the application returns from background, toolbar that is originally positioned at the bottom of the view moves to the top of the view just below navigation controller. This happens only after multitasking and after applicationWillEnterForeground method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had resolved the code by setting frames of tab bar controller when the app returns from background

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NIB-file even if you use a custom `UITableViewController` subclass. The exact class to use can be specified on the identity tab of the inspector in Interface Builder.[image: Class Identity]
<sub>(source: [peylow.se](http://www.peylow.se/ClassIdentity.png))</sub>

If you are having problem when multitasking, then I suspect you do not properly handle unloading of the view. Your app can unload views from view controllers when going to the background in order to free more memory.

It is important that you make sure that any connection that is setup/created in `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` is also properly disconnected/released in `viewDidUnload`. Otherwise strange and unexpected things can happen to your app.

Comment: Sorry, I cant use it that way. I tried but cant change the class name there.

Comment: @Dimple Panchal - Why? The textfield where you write the class name is **never** read-only. Do observe that if you need custom setup than you must override `initWithCoder:` or `awakeFromNib` as needed.

Comment: My custom class is not having any xib file. So might be that is the reason. I am not sure about the reason but I suspect this reason. I tried this at first only.